# How to get the document height at different zoom level?

Tags: javascript

I am using ASP.NET and C#.

```
document.documentelement.offsetHeight
```

I am using this to find the height of the page. But it is differing based on zoom level. Now i need to get the base height(at 100% zoom) at all zoom level. Because using this i am doing some calculation to set height of other tags.

Is it possible?

**Edit:**

I did used this to detect the zoom level

```
((screen.deviceXDPI / screen.systemXDPI) * 100).toFixed();
```

But it is not accurate. Is there any other way to detect the zoom level?

Answer (score 0):

document.height / $(document).height() should give you the zoom level. I've tested this on chrome - requires jquery

Comment: You might want to consider adding a snippet of code to your answer.  Be sure to test it before saving.